# Sort table taking into consideration blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way or code to sort this table in this way?

[image]<-- Before / After -->
[image]

Comment: How would it know which rows "belong" to which first-column non-blank values?  I suspect you'll either need to populate the blank entries with actual values or combine those cells with the ones that have values to create multi-row cells in that column.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column with gaps is ColumnA and that you have a blank row as Row1 in a spare helper column (say D) insert in Row2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A2),D1,A2)
```

copy down then sort on that.

Before sorting:

[image]

After sorting:

[image]

Comment: Nice. I took the liberty to test and add screenshots.